# Add number for each matching pattern in a txt file in bash

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Hello I have a file such as

File.txt

```
>LO_D
AHAHAHAHHAHAH
>LEIO_DS
DHHDHDHDHDH
>LODJ_jdjd
DJDJHDHDHD
>LO_D
AAAAAAA
>LO_D
HHAHAHAHAHAH
```

An I would like to add a number just after each `>LO_D` element

I should then get:

```
>LO_D_1
AHAHAHAHHAHAH
>LEIO_DS
DHHDHDHDHDH
>LODJ_jdjd
DJDJHDHDHD
>LO_D_2
AAAAAAA
>LO_D_3
HHAHAHAHAHAH
```

Comment: I know how to use sed ex : ```sed -i 's@>LO_D@>LO_D_number@'g File.txt```, but I do not know how to include  the number part.

Comment: Please add this attempt by editing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^(>LO_D)$/"${1}_" . ++$i/e;' in.fasta
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`^(>LO_D)$` : Match the literal string `>LO_D` that starts at the beginning of the line (`^`) and ends at the end of the line (`$`). Capture the string using parentheses into capture variable `$1`.
`"${1}_" . ++$i` : Replacement string that consists of the captured variable `$1`, followed by an underscore, followed by the counter. Note that `$1` is written as `${1}` to avoid being interpreted as non-existent variable `$1_`. The counter is incremented by 1 before the expression is evaluated, so that the counter is 1, 2, 3, etc on subsequent matches.
`s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/e` : The `/e` flag tells Perl to evaluate `REPLACEMENT` as an expression first, then do the substitution.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 5):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '/^>LO_D$/ {$0 = $0 "_" (++n)} 1' file

>LO_D_1
AHAHAHAHHAHAH
>LEIO_DS
DHHDHDHDHDH
>LODJ_jdjd
DJDJHDHDHD
>LO_D_2
AAAAAAA
>LO_D_3
HHAHAHAHAHAH
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '$0==">LO_D"{print $0"_"++count;next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
$0==">LO_D"{           ##Checking condition if line is >LO_D then do following.
  print $0"_"++count   ##Printing current line _ count variable with inreasing value.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                      ##1 will print current line.
' Input_file           ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```